# Cookie created on page called by Jquery Ajax not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I have a page that does a AJAX call with jQuery to log a user in by setting a cookie on the ajax-called page. When I travel to another page in Firefox, Safari Chrome, etc, the login has worked.
But in IE6-9 the cookie isn't set. I did find some tips on specific header settings to satisfy IE's security preferences, but those all pertained to ajax calls to external domains, I am calling a page on the same domain ( by a relative path ). I tried it anyway, and it didn't work. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to the path of the cookie set by the ajax request. Is it the same as the path of the login cookie you want? ie /my/ajax/request or /my/container/page instead of "/"

I'm working with a similar ajax issue where jquery won't set a cookie from within a loaded ajax block... intermittently :/  very strange

```
$.cookie("my_setting", "true", { path: "/" });
```

simplified cookie path for now. Some browsers may scope cookies differently based on paths.

Also in some situations setting a cookie to false can make logic difficult, so I use string "false" instead of false 0 or null.

Edit:  My issue is limited to firefox 14.  Safari, IE9 and Chrome all have correct cookie behavior, allowing me to set cookies in the "/" scope from an ajax-loaded block, while FF has seemingly intermittent problems doing so.